# Save HasMany and asscoiate BelongsTo in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There is following table structure:

**Users**

- HasMany Pages

**Pages**

- BelongsTo User
- HasMany Notes

**Notes**

- BelongsTo User

To create a note I do:

```
$note = new Note([
    'page_id': $this->page->id,
    'user_id': auth()->id(),
    'title': 'Foobar'
]);
$note->save();
```

Easy. Because of mass assignment vulnerability I want to avoid having foreign keys inside fillable of the note model. The code changes to:

```
$note = $this->page->notes()->create([
    'title': 'Foobar'
]);
$note->user()->associate(auth()->user());
$note->save();
```

Fuzzy. For this to work I have to make the user_id of note nullable in the migration. This feels wrong because a note should never exist without a user. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: can a page only have 1 user and a note only belong to one page?  looks like a good place to use a HasManyThrough relationship where a User has many Notes through Pages.  (making Notes belongTo Page and not user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```php
$note = new Note([
   'title' => 'your_title_here' //works if title is in the fillable attributes
]);
$note->page()->associate($this->page);
$note->user()->associate(auth()->user());
$note->save();
```

Here, you don't need any nullable column and there are no risks about mass assignment.

Another advantage, there is only one database query instead of two when you are doing `create` first then another `save`.